# VBA: adding up irregular ranges

Tags: vba, excel, sum, range

[image: Pic of the Excel Sheet to illustrate the explanation below]

I need some help to create a macro which adds all the values on the column E between the rows with the "avg"  word. the result should be displayed on the cells where the "Sum here" label is displayed. Both texts "avg" and "sum here" is just for illustrate the example, "avg" could be replaced by any other word and "sum here" should actually be the aggregation of the values above it.

The real challenge is that the number of ranges on column E is variable, so i would like to find a macro which is able to deal with "n" number of ranges on column E.

Finally, the values on column D are only the example of the expected value on the "sum here" cells.

This is what I have tried to far:

```
        Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim sumhere As Range
Dim startingpoint As Range
Dim endingpoint As Range

'
    Range("C17").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    If ActiveCell = "avg" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=2).Select
        
        
        Set sumhere = ActiveCell
        Set startingpoint = ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=-1, columnoffset:=0)
        
        
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        If (ActiveCell.Value) = "Sum here" Then
        Set endingpoint = ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=1, columnoffset:=0)
        sumhere.Formula = "=sum(range(startingpoint:endingpoint)"
        
        
            
        Else
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        If (ActiveCell.Value) = "Sum here" Then
        Set endingpoint = ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=1, columnoffset:=0)
        sumhere.Formula = "=Sum(Range(startingpoint.adress:endingpoint.adress))"
        
     
        Else: End If
        End If
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Additionally, as you can see, I do not know, how to define a range using variables. My original idea was to combine this code with some kind of "do while" or/and "for i= 1 to x" and "next i". But I can't see how to combine it.

Comment: Hi Suances! Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: Just start by setting the total to 0, then loop through each row and either (a) if column C is not "avg" (or whatever you use) then add the value of column E to the total, or (b) if column C is "avg" (or whatever you use) write the total to column E and set the total to 0 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you just need something like:

```
Sub sums()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

j = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row
k = 1

For i = 1 To j
    If Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then
        Range("E" & i).Value = "=Sum(E" & k & ":E" & i - 1 & ")"
        k = i + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Using formula only, and providing that column A only has `avg` (or any text) on each subtotal row.

I've given two versions of the formula - the volatile version (updates everytime you change anything on the spreadsheet), and the non-volatile version (only updates if it needs to).

The formula should be entered on row 6 - change the `$E6` to which ever row you need.

*(volatile)*

```
=SUM(OFFSET($E6,IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1)<>""),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1))),0)-ROW()+1,,ROW()-1-IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1)<>""),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1))),0)))
```

*(non volatile)*:

```
=SUM(INDEX($E:$E,IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1)<>""),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1))),0)+1):INDEX($E:$E,ROW()-1))
```

---

or if you don't mind using a helper column:

In cell B6:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1)<>""),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1))),0)
```

In E6: *(volatile)*

```
=SUM(OFFSET($E6,$B6-ROW()+1,,ROW()-1-$B6))
```

or *(non volatile)*:

```
=SUM(INDEX($E:$E,$B6):INDEX($E:$E,ROW()-1))
```

**Edit:**
Thought I'd add a UDF to calculate it to if you're after VBA.

Use the function `=AddSubTotal()` in the rows you want the sub total to be shown in, or use `=AddSubTotal("pop",6)` to sum everything in column F (col 6) using "pop" rather than "avg".

```
Public Function AddSubTotal(Optional Delim As String = "avg", Optional ColNumber = 5) As Double

    Dim rCaller As Range
    Dim rPrevious As Range
    Dim rSumRange As Range

    Set rCaller = Application.Caller

    With rCaller.Parent
        Set rPrevious = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rCaller.Row - 1, 1)).Find(Delim, , , , , xlPrevious)
        If Not rPrevious Is Nothing Then
            Set rSumRange = rPrevious.Offset(1, ColNumber - 1).Resize(rCaller.Row - rPrevious.Row - 1)
        Else
            Set rSumRange = .Range(.Cells(1, ColNumber), .Cells(rCaller.Row - 1, ColNumber))
        End If
    End With

    AddSubTotal = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rSumRange)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The following VBA routine assumes that

- your data is in Columns C:E
- Nothing else relevant (nothing numeric) in that range
- Your "key word" where you want to show the sum is `avg`
- `avg` (the key word) is hard-coded in the macro

You could easily modify this routine to also perform an average of those values, and put those results, for example, in Column D

Any  of the above are easily modified

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub TotalSubRanges()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, rSrc As Range
    Dim dAdd As Double
    Dim I As Long
    Const sKey As String = "avg"

Set rSrc = Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
vSrc = rSrc

'Do the "work" in a VBA array, as this will
'  execute much faster than working directly
'  on the worksheet

For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    If vSrc(I, 1) = sKey Then
        vSrc(I, 3) = dAdd
        dAdd = 0
    Else
        If IsNumeric(vSrc(I, 3)) Then dAdd = dAdd + vSrc(I, 3)
    End If
Next I

'write the results back to the worksheet
' and conditionally format the "sum" cells
With rSrc
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vSrc
    .Columns(3).AutoFit
    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = .Columns(3).ColumnWidth
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add _
        Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=" & .Item(1, 1).Address(False, True) & "=""" & sKey & """"
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End With
End With 

End Sub
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change:
Dim startingpoint As Range
Dim endingpoint As Range

To:
Dim startingpoint As Variant
Dim endingpoint As Variant

As the startingpoint and endingpoint is used in a formula, you cant define them as a Range.